# Saving the response of $.get as a variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
function foobar(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
    var response = $.get("http://mysite.com/return.php")
    document.write(response);
}
```

I'm trying to save the response from this as a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't explained very well, but using the async: false, it works.

Comment: **Do not use `async: false`**! It will freeze the browser.

Comment: It doesn't.  Tried it on all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*$.get* is an asynchronous AJAX call - your *document.write* line is going to execute long before the server even sends you a response.

If you want to access the return value, you'll need to do it in a callback, like so:

```
$.get('/return.php', function(response) {
  document.write(response);
});
```

Comment: so everything must be in there?

Comment: @jdborg Yes, that's how asynchronous programming works. The `get` function returns before the response comes back.

Comment: i'm giving you a -1 as a flag because you didn't notice that `document.write` is being called asynchronously, which will mean that the *entire* page will be overwritten.

Comment: Such a shame that many people seem to be using AJAX without the faintest clue about what it is.

Comment: Tomalak we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, I took the time to *read* about AJAX before trying it out. It would be nice if others would do the same.

Comment: Reading and experiencing is two different things. Reading about driving, is not the same as driving....

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to do that unless you use `$.ajax` with the `async` option set to `false`. Otherwise, the callback used for AJAX will execute after the document is closed for writing, and you'll overwrite your entire page.

Instead, use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to dump obligatory HTML into the page asynchronously.

Comment: I don't want to load a page using it, I want to use it to return a variable (mysql / glob that kind of thing).

Comment: @jdborg, `load` isn't loading a page. It's adding HTML content to the page. `document.write` is adding HTML content to the page as well; if you're simply trying to get a variable from the server, you're doing it ***very*** wrong.

Comment: then please explain a better way.

Comment: @jdborg, return a JSON object from the server, and the first parameter of the success callback *is* the variable. If you need to store it globally, you could use `function(data){window.globalpollution=data;}` as a success callback.

Comment: I'm trying to run a glob using php.  So all the return.php does is give a list of file names.  I can't see how I can do that using this.

Comment: @jdborg, if you're returning textual data, then `data` will just be a string.

Answer (score 0):

$.get provides a success() function for handling the response...

```
function foobar(){
    var response = null;
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
    $.get("http://mysite.com/return.php").success(function(respText) { 
            response = respText; 
            document.write(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $.load() function for this as this is it's intended purpose

See http://api.jquery.com/load/

From the manual:

This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the method can be quite simple:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Comment: I don't want to load a page using it, I want to use it to return a variable (mysql / glob that kind of thing).

Comment: This will complete the equivalent of your original post including the document.write bit. However, it wont store it in a variable. If you're not intending to write the response to the page then load() is indeed unsuitable, but then equally your OP is misleading.

Comment: No, I said I wanted to save it as a variable.